# Can a generic for PRIMARY KEY be used in a SQL WHERE clause for use with dynamic queries?

Tags: sql

Is there a way to create a generic SQL query against the primary key in the WHERE clause?  so I could pass a table name ($table) and value from the primary key column ($id) and get the correct results with the following:

```
SELECT * FROM $table WHERE <<PRIMARY KEY??>>=$id
```

Thank you for your kind attention :)

Comment: Yes, but not with the engine only. You need an application layer to do that.

Comment: Not in standard SQl no. You would need to tell us your database backend for a database specifc solution if there is one. However, this is NOT something you would want to do in most databases. It is untestable for one and databases design their execution plans based on the specifics and you could end up with very poor perfornmance if the plan for one table is significantly different than the plan for a differnt table.  Further it is a bad idea to use select * any production query. Generalizing is a bad idea in database development, this is not object oriented programming.

Comment: And what happens when your PK for one table is a coumpound PK?

Comment: This can also create a path for SQL injection.

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1406316788&sr=8-1&keywords=sql+antipatterns

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback - Seems like I'll need to find another solution